# Sending email via javax.mail API. Some html properties of the message are ignored

Tags: java, sendmail

I'm sending an email via javax mail API. The body of the email is html content. But the actual received message lacks some of the html properties (fonts, background, etc). I suppose that I must add some headers to the message like...

```
message.addHeader(arg0, arg1);
```

But I don't know what the exact arguments are supposed to be.

Additional info: currently I don't add any headers to the message instance.

Answer (score 5):

You have to call `MimeMessage.setContent(java.lang.Object o, java.lang.String type)` method.

```
message.setContent(htmlBody,"text/html");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
. . . . . 
MimeMultipart alternative = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
MimeBodyPart text = new MimeBodyPart();
MimeBodyPart html = new MimeBodyPart();
text.setText("text content");
html.setContent("html content", "text/html");
alternative.addBodyPart(text);
alternative.addBodyPart(html);
. . . . .
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setContent(alternative);
```